# Group of units in $\mathbb{Z}\left[{\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}}\right]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have to prove that the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}\left[{\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}}\right]$ is equal to $\pm 1$ and given the fact that is a UFD I have to show that the only integral solution of $x^2+19=y^3$ is $(\pm 18,7)$.

I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Factor $x^2+19$ over $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2]$ and use it is a UFD to conclude the factors are cubes.  Equate coefficients...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the units of the ring, just use the [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm). Given unit $\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{2}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ (and $a\equiv b\operatorname{ mod } 2$, but this is not used in the next), its norm $\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{2}\frac{a-b\sqrt{-19}}{2}$ must be a integral unit in $\mathbb Z$, hence $a^2+19b^2=4$, obviously $b=0$, for otherwise the LHS $\ge 19$, and $a=\pm 2$.

As to solve the Diophantine equation, the method suggested in the comment is worked out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551556/integer-solutions-of-x3-19-y2), for which it's necessary to know each unit is a cube. I'll be interested in an approach based on [$y^2=x^3-19$](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/12996/f/1) is clearly an elliptic curve, but haven't found one yet.

**Edit** At first, I thought the OP means to reduce the problem of finding the units to the solution of the equation, until @user10354138 corrected me in the comment.

Comment: You have shown the only units are $\pm 1$, which are obviously cubes.

Comment: Yes, but the OP wanted to solve the equation without first knowing the units, otherwise there is no need to solve the equation.

Comment: I read the question differently.  The OP probably was given the exercise in two parts.  Part (a) prove there are no additional units, part (b) solve the equation given it is a UFD.  That's why there is a "I don't really know where to start" as a justification of PSQ.